# iframe appear in debug console firefox but there isn't in file.css

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, iframe

I've a problem with the part css. I'd have to set new width of the iframe, but the problem when i try to find in file css it is not there.
I try also to put in file.css the path-class for setting my iframe but with out result.there someone that could give me some advice on resolve this problem? here the code part php end css. Thanks in adavance.

Here the image:
[image]

Edit*

I'VE RESOLVED. i'm achieved the parent class end i've modified iframe directly in css file. Anyway thanks everybody also just for having gave a glance.

Comment: where is your html code?

Comment: it's over with part code php.(the file is an extension phtml)